# Setting up openfire server

Tags: mysql, localhost, openfire

I am having a problem setting up OpenFire on my localhost.
After setting the localhost database I seem to get this error.

The error appears after i select this option in the setup process:
"Store users and groups in the server database. This is the best option for simple deployments."

The web browser shows the following error:
"Problem accessing /setup/setup-profile-settings.jsp. Reason: 
    Server Error
Caused by:
java.lang.NullPointerException"

My database has been set up but there are no tables in it. 
Could it be that I need to create a table with two rows: Users and Groups?

Where is the file setup-profile-settings.jsp? What type of file is this?
Could it be on my localhost server?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

If your database has no tables, then you are missing the **Setup the Database** step.

You have to import the schema file into your MySQL database from `resources/database` directory of the installation folder.
Guide for setting up database for MySQL (and other database) can be found here: http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/database.html

Full installation guide http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/install-guide.html